# URL-parameters to JSF form component action attribute

Tags: jsf-2.2

Is there any good way to add URL-parameters to the rendered action attribute of a jsf form component ?
If there is a solution it has to be functioning without JavaScript.

Comment: how are you planning to retrieve and use them in action method? would `f:setPropertyActionListener` be sufficient for you?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. My attempt was to show a modal dialogue (containing a form) in the UI when a specific parameter were present in the URL. However, I did implement another solution by making a base facelet-template with a bool-flag in a session bean (to choose between two implementations of the template, one showing the modal and the other one not)